# Email Parsing program

Tags: c#, parsing, outlook, html-agility-pack

I am writing email parsing program. Basically, I am trying to retrieve the emails from exchange server and they have different formats. Mail body contains p and span tags, and when I open the message in Outlook, it is adding additional classes such as "msonormal" to the html elements. And when I copy and paste it in GMail composer it is just removing the classes but html tags are intact.

I am using HTML agility pack to parse the tags independent of class names. Emails are sent via different automated systems. So, I am not completely sure if the emails from the exchange server contains p and span tags or the outlook/gmail editors are adding those tags as well.

Can any one shed some light, do these mail editors just add the classes or any additional attributes or they completely change the layout such as showing divs as tables.

Comment: I am sorry, it is kind of theory question. My intention to get some knowledge on HTML editors and their behavior. Let me know if this forum is inappropriate

Comment: While I don't know the answer to your specific question (what the mail editors do), it seems to me that for your parser to be at all robust, it's going to have to contend with all these things and more.  What are you trying to parse out of the emails?

Comment: Emails contain invoices but there are many formats for different clients. We are using html tags to traverse through the mails but curios to know how HTML editors behave before we research for text body.

Comment: Are you asking whether the sending program modifies the email text body, or the receiving (reader) app/web page? Or both?

Comment: I would like to know if I copy the mail in any mail editor, how do they behave

Comment: I got some info. from this link that editors do alter the markup 
https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/rendering-engines/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but if you are getting emails from different sources, chances are that they will all be formatted differently.

You're on the right track using html agility pack. I would suggest putting a break point in your code and getting the full html source of each and then parsing.

They are from different sources so you can conditionally parse based on sender or subject.

I've had to do this in the past, it was a pain, sorry there is no way to normalize all so they can be parsed in a standard way. The only way would be for you to enforce a standard on your senders, which I'm guessing would be almost impossible.